# NHibernate LINQ + PLINQ

Tags: linq, nhibernate, plinq

i've just started reading up on PLINQ and find it fasinating.

I'm using NHib->Linq in my projects - does anyone know if there's any benefit/problems using PLINQ type queries with NHLinq?

w://

Comment: reading this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163329.aspx it looks like it's only good for querying in-memory collections - is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to parallelize several NHibernate queries with PLINQ, keep in mind that NHibernate's ISession is not thread-safe. You have to use a new ISession for each step of the PLINQ loop, since each step can potentially run in another thread.

If you're trying to use PLINQ constructs *within* a single NHibernate query at best you'll get an exception since SQL itself does not have any parallelizing constructs.