# Repository pattern with PLinq

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, asp.net-4.0, plinq

I am fairly new to Plinq and Repo pattern. I nee some references and guidlines from you for implementation of Repository pattern using dbml, PLinq in fx 4.0

Comment: Are you sure you mean PLINQ? i.e. concurrent/task based LINQ?

Comment: I am just going through the MSDN article and thought,i wish i could implement it in my repository as i use L2S with repo. I dont know any thing about Pling.

Comment: @AmitRanjan: And, um... Why would you want to use it for implementing the repository pattern?

Comment: Just for curiosity. I want to know, if its possible and useful , then i will definitely going to use it my coming projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repository pattern provides you with abstraction over the data storage. PLINQ with repository pattern will work if the underlined storage is ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163329.aspx#S2)):

- (in-memory) `T[]`, `List<T>`, or any other kind of `IEnumerable<T>`
- XML documents loaded using the `System.Xml.Linq` APIs

It will not work with:

- LINQ-to-SQL or LINQ-to-Entities ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163329.aspx#S2))
- [NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780422/nhibernate-linq-plinq)

Answer (score 0):

In short, NO - PLINQ is not supported for Linq to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

PLINQ and Repository are unrelated concepts:

- PLINQ is a way to process large amounts of in-memory data in parallel. Data access speeds are assumed to be in the nanosecond range.
- Repository is a way to access data from a persistent storage in an object oriented way, that hides the way data is actually persisted and retrieved. Data access speeds are assumed to be in the millisecond range.